# If Statement Returning True All The Time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check if the input is true, and continue to next word if false.

```
        "Apples",
        "Bananas",
        "Pears",
        "Door",
        "Towel",
        "Computer",
    ];


    var x = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

function clearbox(){
    if (x = myInput.value){
        var x = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random();*myArray.length)]);
        document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = x
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''   ;
    }
    };
```

For some reason the if statment is not working, can someone help please?

Comment: The answers below recommend to use `==` , however sometimes it is much better to also check the type via `===`. So that means using `if(var === value)`  instead of `if(var == value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement `if (x = myInput.value)` should be using a boolean comparison operator (`==`), but you used an assignment operator (`=`) instead. As a result, the variable `x` is being set to the value `myInput.value` which will always return true, as values > 0 are interpreted to be true <s>by the compiler</s>. Instead, your function should read:

```
function clearbox(){
    if (x == myInput.value){
        var x = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]);
        document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''
        document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = x
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''   ;
    }
```

Comment: _..to be true by the compiler.._ No compiler :) JavaScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled language

Comment: oh darn! I just realized this is javascript not C++ LOL! cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be using `==` instead of `=` which results in `true` always (you can also use `===` for type checking as well):

```
if (x == myInput.value)
```

2. You have a syntax error here (remove the `;`):

```
var x = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)]);
```